# Python regex for alphanumerics not working

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine

```
from django import forms
class ActonForm(forms.Form):
    creator = forms.RegexField('^[a-zA-Z0-9\-' ]$',max_length=30, min_length=3)

data = {'creator': 'hello'
        }
f = ActonForm(data)
print f.is_valid()
```

Why doesn't this work? have i made a wrong regular expression? I wanted a name field with provision for single quotes and a hyphen

Comment: -1: That's the worst question title ever.  Is this a "regular expression doesn't work" question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It kind of shows in the syntax highlighting. The apostrophe in the regex isn't escaped, it should be like this:

```
forms.RegexField('^[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\' ]$',max_length=30, min_length=3)
```

**Edit:** When escaping things in the regular expression, you need double backslashes. I doubled the backslash before the hyphen (not that it has to be escaped in this particular case.)

Secondly, your regular expression only allows for a single character. You need to use a quantifier. + means one or more, * means 0 or more, {2,} means two or more, {3,6} means three to six. You probably want this:

```
forms.RegexField('^[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\' ]+$',max_length=30, min_length=3)
```

Do take care that the above regular expression will allow spaces in the start and end of the field as well. To avoid that you need a more complex regex.

Comment: The hyphen is also in the wrong place - hyphens in character classes aren't backslash escaped, instead they should be the first or last character.

Comment: Hyphens can be escaped just like any other special meaning character. However, placing them first or last in a character class can be considered good practice as it improves readability slightly.